# What does the `android.intent.extra.showActionIcons` parameter control?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I would like to take a photo with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent, but disable the settings button in the top-left corner. I was able to find a [EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS) parameter, but it is not well documented. This is the description:

```
The name of an Intent-extra used to control the UI of a ViewImage. This is a boolean property that specifies whether or not to show action icons.
```

Even if I set it true or false, nothing changes. What does this parameter do? I use it like this:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to take a photo with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, but disable the settings button in the top-left corner

As I have pointed out [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039778/115145), you do not have control over the UI of a third-party camera apps. There are hundreds of such apps; none have to give you any ability to control their UI.

> What does this parameter do?

Based on [a search of the Android source code](https://cs.android.com/search?q=EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS%20OR%20showActionIcons), it does nothing in Android itself. If the device happens to have the AOSP Gallery app installed, it appears to control something in the image viewer there. It is certainly possible that some non-AOSP apps use that extra for some particular reason, but that behavior would vary by app.